# NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSelect! After upgrade to angular material 15

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-15

I have updated angular project from v14 to v15.0.4 and mat-select throws the error.
It was fully working before upgrading.

Angular version : 15.0.4
Angular Material version : 15.0.4

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(TestModule)[MatSelect -> MatSelect -> MatSelect]: NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSelect!
```

Current still using the legacy-select, imported in material.module.ts and it's imported in app module

```
import {MatLegacySelectModule as MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/legacy-select';

imports: [
        MatSelectModule,
    ],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still use MatLegacySelectModule and use [ngx-mat-select-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search?activeTab=readme) dependency, make sure you are in version 6.x.x. (Cf Compatibility part)

Comment: If you use 7.0.0 version, it was giving error for me, it has to be 6.x.x

Comment: We have updated to Angular 16, but are still using the legacy components. Therefore I installed ngx-mat-select-search in version 6.0.0 and added an override for @angular/core and @angular/material to version 16 in the package.json. Works great. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
```

Comment: it generates error: "Multiple components match node with tagname mat-form-field: MatLegacyFormField and MatFormField."

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ngx-mat-select-search then MatLegacySelectModule (@angular/material/legacy-select) of @angular/material@15 is not supported anymore, please use version 6.0.0

you can read it here [ngx-mat-select-search - yarn package manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search?activeTab=readme)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).